# Как поменять активный класс при скролле предыдущему/текущему/следующему блоку?

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Всем привет.

Есть неограниченное количество контейнеров на странице, например

```html
<section class="Scrn Scrn_1 active">Lorem</section>
<section class="Scrn Scrn_2">Ipsum</section>
<section class="Scrn Scrn_3">Dolor</section>
<section class="Scrn Scrn_4">Sit</section>
<section class="Scrn Scrn_5">Amet</section>
```

Первый блок с классом "active" `position: relative;`, остальные `position: fixed;`. Когда первый блок полностью скрывается - у следующего за ним должен добавиться  класс "active", чтоб его тоже можно было прокрутить.

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать?

Comment: Покажите ваш код и что не получается? как вариант по блокам пробегайтесь .each() при скролле и всё. Ну это для jquery

Comment: @Nilsan Собственно пока только скилет из блоков. Не знаю как реализовать переключение классов.

Comment: эмммм... Ну так вот делаете функцию которая вызывается при скролле, в функции через .each() бегаете по классама и проверяете например отступ от верха и исходя из этого даёте класс нужный

Comment: @Nilsan у всех блоков отступ = 0. Каким образом отслеживать следующий блок и делать его потом активным?

Comment: Окей, вот вам нужно решение проблемы, но вы даже условий не даёте :-( Куда у вас там первый блок скрывается? Вверх? Считайте при скроле тогда когда "дно" блока будет там где вам нужно и меняйте класс

Comment: Из стопки блоков верхний, при скролле, уходит вверх. Как при этом предыдущему/текущему/следующему блоку сменить класс?

Comment: Вверх? Считайте при скроле тогда когда "дно" блока будет там где вам нужно и меняйте класс